# Having problems using user forms in module

Tags: excel, userform, vba

I initially used Application.Inputbox to take the user input which worked fine. But when I wanted to increase the options it exceeded 254 character limit. Thus had to use userform. I am new to userforms.
I used user input to choose the case statements.
The userform basically contains a combobox(CmbType), an attached label and the commandbutton(ok). It looks fine and added the RowSource property in the property. All the options could be  seen when executed.
Userform  Complete Code:

```
 Sub ok_Click()
Type = CmbType.Value
Unload UserForm1
End Sub
```

Module Code:

```
Sub  Ingredients()
Dim statements
UserForm1.Show
Select Case Type
Case Is= “Fruits”
….
Case Is =”Vegetables”
…
End Select
Unload UserForm1
…..
…..
```

I am getting the userform but it is not closing and basically not going to the case statements.One more help that I need is to create a numeric to be used in case statement like 1-Fruits,2-Vegetables etc.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looks like you are dealing with variable scope.

Create a module called globals. In the module declare

```
Public iType as integer
```

You can access that from anywhere in your project.
Don't use the variable name Type. It is a reserved word.

In the form ok button click use

```
iType = CmbType.Value
Unload me
```

In the module use

```
UserForm1.Show
Select Case iType
Case 1
   'Fruits
Case 2
   'Vegetables
Case Else
   'Not sure what this food is
End Select
```

Here is a bit more info on how case statements can be used.  http://www.techonthenet.com/excel/formulas/case.php

Also, look in to "Option Explicit".  Adding that at the top of each form and module will let you know of issues like variables that you are trying to use that are not in scope.